# Perl deleting array elements after a few iterations of code, with a call to a sub function

Tags: arrays, perl, branch-and-bound

My code works for the first few iterations, but after a few times through the while loop, it seems that my array elements are being deleted.

I'm taking numbers off the array constructed from the input parameters and all I can tell is that when I get to a number which was passed in twice, I get an error.

I am calling my script like this

```
./branchandboundNoComments.pl 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 7 9 9 10 10 12 14 19
```

I should get this as output

```
0, 7, 9, 10, 14, 19
```

This is my script

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;

my @input  = @ARGV;
my $maxAll = $input[-1];
$#input = $#input - 1;
my @multiset = ( 0, $maxAll );
my @stack;

my $rotation = 0;    # this is 0,1, or 2.

while ( @input != 0 ) {

    my $max = $input[-1];

    my @deltamultiset;
    for ( my $i = 1; $i <= $#multiset; $i++ ) {
        push @deltamultiset, $multiset[$i] - $max;
    }
    push @deltamultiset, $max;

    my @deltamultiset2;
    for ( my $i = 1; $i <= $#multiset; $i++ ) {
        push @deltamultiset2, $multiset[$i] - ( $maxAll - $max );
    }
    push @deltamultiset2, $max;

    if ( subset( \@deltamultiset, \@input ) and $rotation == 0 ) {

        for ( my $i = 0; $i < $#deltamultiset; $i++ ) {
            pop @input;
        }

        push @multiset, $max;
        push @stack,    $max;
        push @stack,    0;
    }
    elsif ( subset( \@deltamultiset2, \@input ) and $rotation <= 1 ) {

        for ( my $j = 0; $j < $#deltamultiset; $j++ ) {
            pop @input;
        }

        push @multiset, ( $maxAll - $max );
        push @stack,    ( $maxAll - $max );
        push @stack, 1;
        $rotation = 0;
    }
    elsif ( @stack != 0 ) {

        $rotation = $stack[-1];
        $#stack--;
        $max = $stack[-1];
        $#stack--;
        $rotation++;

        for ( my $i = 0; $i < $#multiset; $i++ ) {
            if ( $multiset[$i] == $max ) {
                delete $multiset[$i];
                last;
            }
        }

        for ( my $i = 0; $i < $#deltamultiset; $i++ ) {
            push @input, $deltamultiset[$i];
        }
    }
    else {
        print "no solutions \n";
        exit;
    }
}

print "@multiset is a solution \n";

sub subset {
    my ( $deltamultisetSubref, $multisetSubref ) = @_;
    my @deltamultisetSub = @{$deltamultisetSubref};
    my @multisetSub      = @{$multisetSubref};

    while ( @deltamultisetSub != 0 ) {

        for ( my $i = $#multisetSub; $i >= -1; $i-- ) {

            if ( $multisetSub[$i] == $deltamultisetSub[-1] ) {
                pop @deltamultisetSub;
                $#multisetSub--;
                last;
            }

            if ( $i == -1 ) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is what is output

```
Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at ./branchandboundNoComments.pl line 20.
Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at ./branchandboundNoComments.pl line 26.
no solutions
```

Comment: You can use -1 to index the last array element, no need for `$#`. I'm not sure if you're realized that assigning to `$#` modifies the array. Your loops seem to sometimes skip the first element, and sometimes skip the last. You're unnecessarily copying array references to examine their contents.

Anyway, I'm too confused by now to figure out what you're actually trying to achieve.

I'm pretty sure the problem is the if statement that assigns instead of comparing, and the subsequent `delete` on an array (I think you meant to use `splice`).

Comment: Re "*I'm pretty sure the problem is the if statement that assigns instead of comparing*", meaning that `if ($multiset[$i] = $max)` should be `if ($multiset[$i] == $max)`

Comment: And please!!! Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! (I see that you used `-w`, which is an acceptable replacement for the latter.)

Comment: @ikegami Oh right, sorry about that, I fixed a few things and updated my code, I took some of the print tests out because I decided it was more clear

Comment: `$max = $stack[-1]; $#stack--;` is better written as `$max = pop @stack;`

Comment: Is this algorithm described on line anywhere? I'd like to understand what your code is meant to do, as there's no way of distinguishing what's correct from what's not.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand the algorithm you're trying to implement, so there are probably more errors, but the immediate problem is that the statement

```
delete $multiset[$i]
```

won't remove that element from the array unless it is the last element; otherwise the array stays the same length, `exists` on that element will return *false*, and it will evaluate to `undef`

If you want to *remove* the element, which seems most likely, then you want

```
splice @multiset, $i, 1;
```

But I have tested your code with that fix in place, and while it no longer produces *Use of uninitialized value in subtraction* errors, the result is still 
*no solutions*

Unfortunately I can't understand what you're trying to implement, and can't make any useful guesses about what may be wrong unless you can offer me a description of the underlying algorithm